# Finding references to page and slot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a DB for which DBCC CHECKDB produces the output with following lines among others:

```
Table error: Object ID 437576597, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594473545728, alloc unit ID 72057594040549376 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:9689715), slot 4, text ID 11927732027392 does not match its reference from page (1:9697074), slot 2.
Table error: Object ID 437576597, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594473545728, alloc unit ID 72057594040549376 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:9689715), slot 4, text ID 0 is pointed to by page (1:9689715), slot 5 and by page (1:9697074), slot 2.
```

So I go and check the entries at `(1:9689715), slot 5` and `(1:9697074), slot 2`. First one seem to be correct, second one is not. I want to find table and row which references it. As far as I understand for that I need to find another page (and slot) that references the incorrect one and keep backtracking until the slot contains row data. Question is how do I do that backtracking?

DBCC PAGE output for page `1:9697074` contains following under `slot 2`:

```
Blob row at: Page (1:9697074) Slot 2 Length: 98 Type: 5 (LARGE_ROOT_YUKON)

Version Infomation: Transaction Timestamp  (0) 
Version Pointer (Null)

Blob Id: 9242676756480 Level: 0 MaxLinks: 5 CurLinks: 1

    Child 0 at Page (1:9689715) Slot 4 Size: 1072 Offset: 1072
```

I don't need to recover anything at this point, just find the affected row(s).

Comment: The second error message might be a red herring. Difficult to know from this side of the screen. Does this help? http://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/11/05/sql-server-storage-engine-lob-storage/